# mod_rewrite question

Tags: mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite http://www.example.com/ to http://www.example.com/new ?

Comment: That depends.  Are you trying to rewrite in the URL bar?  Just set a default page?  Could you provide more details on what you want?

Comment: I just need the URL to look as http://www.example/com/new when a user first visits the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with other mods. But with mod_rewrite you have to create a .htaccess file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /new/ [R]
```

The Options directive may not be necessary. The ^$ stands for an "empty" request, the first visit. [R] means that it should be an external redirection.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to rewrite the / to the new directory use :

```
RewriteRule ^$ /new/ [R]
```